# Underlayment Situation

Tags: subfloor, hardwood-floor, underlayment

I have a small "mill house" built in 1936 with 1,094 sq ft. It was all hardwood floors but now everything has been changed to plywood subfloor except the 2 bedrooms. The kitchen and bath were remodeled and a 1/2" underlayment added onto the 3/4 plywood. To get the living area and bedrooms to the same height before putting down LVP, I was going to add 1/2" on top in the bedrooms and living space. Now here is the kicker. In the bedrooms, believe it or not, the hardwood floor is the actual subfloor nailed to the floor joists. So here are my questions:

Is it okay to go on top of the hardwood flooring?

Do I screw the underlayment to the floor joists or just screw into the subfloor?

Comment: Yes you can overlay the hardwood subfloor.  Definitely layout and screw into the joists. If needed you can also screw between the joists into the hardwood covering

Comment: @Kyle, make your comment an answer. It is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can overlay the hardwood subfloor. Definitely layout and screw into the joists. If needed you can also screw between the joists into the hardwood covering.